# Can I use cPanel's redirect feature to redirect the home page and a deep page to another domain?

Tags: redirects, cpanel, error

I want to redirect my main homepage to redirect (e.g. example.com) to a separate website but also redirect other subpages (e.g. example.com/contact) to a separate website as well. But when I redirect my main page it doesn't allow the other subpages to be redirected.

---

**EXAMPLE:**

- `example.com` ---> `example.org`
- `example.com/contact` ---> `example.org/contact`

I use UkCheapHosts to host my website and configure using cPanel. How can this work?

---

If I put a redirect onto `example.com` to redirect to `example.org` it works fine, but when I add another redirect from `example.com/contact` to `example.org/contact`, it doesn't work.  I get 'Error establishing a database connection' when I try to access `example.com/contact`

---

SCREENSHOTS:

**IMAGE ONE - THE REDIRECTS SECTION OF cPANEL**
[image: The Redirects section of cPanel]

**IMAGE TWO - THE NOTES AND INFO SECTION OF REDIRECTS IN cPANEL**
[image: The notes section on the redirects section in cPanel]

**IMAGE THREE - THE ERROR MESSAGE RECIEVED WHEN ACCESSING EXAMPLE.COM/CONTACT PROVING THE REDIRECT HAS NOT COME IN TO PLACE**
[image: The error message recieved when accessing the /contact page after doing the redirect - it shows this message proving the redirect hasn't worked.]

**ALSO PLEASE NOTE THE WILDCARD REDIRECT OPTION HAS NOT WORKED**

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the edit - do you have an answer?

Comment: Does example.org/contact work without the redirect?

Comment: @Steve Yes - `example.org` works without the redirect.